# Is smoothing a causal transformation?

Tags: python, scipy, convolution, smoothing, lowpass-filter

After looking at [such a plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUbwO.png), I'm asked if my smoothing is causal.

Once, during pre-processing, I smooth my raw data using this function:

```
def _smooth(x, data_freq):
    LpFilt_cutoffFreq = 4
    LpFilt_order = 4
    lowpass_filter = scipy.signal.butter(
        LpFilt_order,
        LpFilt_cutoffFreq,
        fs=data_freq,
        output="sos",
    )
    result = scipy.signal.sosfiltfilt(lowpass_filter, x)
    return result
```

and one last time, during my analysis, I smooth the plot like this:

```
signal_avg_conv = np.convolve(signal_avg, np.ones(smoothbin) / smoothbin, 'same')
```

How can I know if my smoothing is causal?

Comment: Well, if giving the same data each time results in different answers, you know it is not causal...

Comment: Thanks @JonCuster, it gives out the exact same result every time, so it must be causal.

Comment: If it gives the same results for the same input it is deterministic. Causal, means that the output at a given moment only depends only on past inputs.

Comment: Thanks @Bob! In the two smoothing steps I apply to my data, do you see any dependence on future inputs?

Comment: Since you are applying it to spatial data that was captured in advance it is causal. But I guess this is not the answer you are looking for. What makes sense to talk about in this context is, how the borders of the image is handled. It seems you are using the `same` mode that will pad the input with zeroes and then crop it to the same shape as the input.